# "The requested method is not implemented" в Битрикс24

Tags: битрикс24

Начал проходить курс по созданию приложений в CRM Битрикс24. Там в первом же уроке выложен исходный код простейшего статического приложения для вывода ФИО сотрудника, его нужно добавить как локальное приложение в Битрикс. Попробовал добавить полностью по инструкции, в итоге получаю ошибку "NotImplementedXXXXXXXXXThe requested method is not implemented" (вместо XXXXXXXXX комбинация из цифр и букв, которая меняется при каждом обновлении страницы).
Проблема остается даже если убрать любые методы работы с библиотекой Битрикса и оставить просто HTML-код - всё равно появляется эта ошибка.
В консоли соответственно та же ошибка (501 Not Implemented). 
При этом если взять ссылку к которой отправляется POST-запрос, и которая и возвращает ошибку 501, и открыть эту ссылку в отдельной вкладке - то HTML-код из виджета там отображается (только не работает по очевидным причинам часть работающая с библиотекой Битрикса).

Может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой или подскажет в каком направлении искать? Поиск по документации Битрикса, а также поиск по 501 ошибке в контексте именно работы с API Битрикса, не дал результатов, к сожалению.

Comment: Точно такая же проблема. Есть подозрение на отсутсвие каких-либо прав, так как это, например, не расширенный тариф. В итоге удалось победить?

Comment: Пока не нашел решения. В сравнениях тарифов не увидел таких ограничений. Мне пока удалось реализовать то, что было нужно через вебхуки. Но, если узнаю что-то новое по сути вопроса - обязательно дополню.

Answer (score 0):

Да уже и коммерческий тариф включили. Смущает, что всегда стоит "Да" в колонке "использует только API", даже если сама галочка в настройках приложения отключена. Возможно это какой-то баг.